# Cannot Tab out of Search Box

Tags: angularjs, search-box

I am using AngularJS advanced search box to create a search box.

While using the keyboard alone (tabbing) , I am unable to navigate to other objects 
My cursor gets stuck inside the search box

Search Box implemented:

```
      <nit-advanced-searchbox ng-model="searchParams"
                              parameters="availableSearchParams"
                              placeholder="Search...">
      </nit-advanced-searchbox>
```

How can I tab out of my search box?

I have attempted to give the seachbox a tabindex but that did not help

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the directive. Have you checked with the developer to see if there are any known issues related to this?

Comment: https://github.com/dnauck/angular-advanced-searchbox/blob/master/src/angular-advanced-searchbox.js line 258 the Tab is getting captured and handled internally, there looks like there is no way to override it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. I contacted the developer. I removed lines 258 - 265 and was still unable to navigate out of the search box

Comment: From developer: As far as I remember, it renders a regular textarea element. Normal focusing should be happening.
Test it out without using a directive and see if it is focusing away. You may have something interacting with your forms perhaps?